# when application become active then how we load the another view or invoke the root view controller

Tags: iphone

i have load the mailcomposer on reciving the localnotification
is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should code as follows,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) 
    {
        //code for opening mail composer
    }



-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
    {
           //code for opening mail composer
    }
```